# Integrating of $\int \sqrt{2-\cos^2(x)}\, dx$

Tags: calculus

I try to substitute $\cos(x)$ with $\sqrt2\cos(\theta)$ but it turns out to be an uglier fraction.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html

Answer (score 1):

We'll need elliptic integrals of the second kind. [Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) $E(x,\,k)=\int_0^x\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}dt$,$$\int_0^x\sqrt{2-\cos^2t}dt=\sqrt{2}\int_{\pi/2-x}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac12\sin^2u}du=\sqrt{2}\left(E\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-E\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x,\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right),$$which [can be rewritten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) as $\sqrt{2}\left(E\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-E\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x,\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$. So$$\int\sqrt{2-\cos^2x}dx=-\sqrt{2}E\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x,\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C.$$